# Grunt Concat Task: How to exclude some files?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, concatenation

I have the following task in grunt:

```
concat: {
       js: {
       src: ['app/**/**/*.js',
             '!app/**/**/*test.js'],
         dest: 'app/scripts.js'
       }
}
```

But it doesn't exclude the js files that finish with `test`. 
What pattern should I use to exclude these files?

Comment: `**` implies subdirectories so I think you mean `['app/**/*.js', '!**/*test.js'],`

Comment: Thanks for the advice,my problem was that I added unnecessary java-script files, to exclude them I had to specify more the route
['app/modules/*/*.js','!app/*/*/*test.js']

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should work:

```
concat: {
  js: {
    src: [
      'app/**/*.js',
      '!**/*test.js'
    ],
    dest: 'app/scripts.js'
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi how can i exclude some particular folder is there any way for that?

Comment: Furthermore, the excluded folders/files need to be after  ** / *